# Android Push Message to Device using parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I Want to send a message to devices that registered to my app in parse, in registration i have added a column `national_id`

and now i want to send a message to specific `national_id`

what i tried:

```
JSONObject obj;
    try {
        obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("alert", "test");
        obj.put("action", "com.parse.pushnotifications.UPDATE_STATUS");
        obj.put("someData", "some additional data ");

        ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("national_id", nationalID);

        push.setQuery(query);
        push.setData(obj);
        push.sendInBackground();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but desired device does not get any message

what is the problem? how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to enable client push notification in parse setting panel

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a few permissions and broadcast receiver information in your app manifest file before you cand send push notifications with parse. Head over to the Parse quickstart guide on push notifications in order to see which lines you have to add.

Your code seems ok, but you have to solve the manifest permission issue.

Comment: thank you, my permission and receiver seems to be ok, because i get notifications from parse panel